# Один в сочетании с существительными

Tags: стилистика

*Предположим, у нас есть подобные примеры:*

**"Вчера один человек проходил мимо нашего дома", "Когда-то давно один герой спас мир", "Один дом был разрушен в результате обвала",** *и так далее. Насколько уместно употреблять слово "один"? Ведь по контексту уже подразумевается, что больше там нет. Не было бы уместнее опустить?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё уместно. В первом предложении "один" означает "некий", "какой-то".
Смотрите значение №3 здесь: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD

Во втором с помощью слова "один" делается смысловое ударение на то, что именно один, а не два, три или десять героев спасли мир. Если бы не было слова один, то имелось бы ввиду, что именно герой, а не фея или волшебник или еще кто-то спас мир.

В третьем то же самое, что и во втором: акцент на число домов.

Answer (score 2):

*Один* используется в разговорной речи (в один прекрасный день; один из присутствующих) в значении местоимения, например:

> Приходил тут один из «Кенгурийской нови». Он написал, что ты убил
> бухгалтера, как несмирившийся сын смирившегося кулака (Ф.А. Искандер,
> «Сандро из Чегема», Книга 1, 1989).

Синонимы слóва-понятия *один*: какой-то, единственный, тот же самый, тождественный, одинаковый, целостный, неделимый, единый, некто, кто-то.